# Hibernate sometimes leaves empty foreign key fields in child entities

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Lately I encountered a strange phenomenon with my Hibernate/Postgres data. On unknown conditions Hibernate creates orphans of child entities (null foreign key field to parent). But I have annotated the @OneToMany relation as orphanRemoval.

The "main" entity:

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class Product {
    @NotNull(groups = { CheckId.class })
    @NotBlank(groups = { CheckId.class })
    @Id
    @Column(length = 32)
    private String id = IdGenerator.createId();

    @Version
    private Integer version;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name=Product.PRODUCT_ID)
    @Index(name="idx_prod_ident")
    private Set<Identifier> identifiers;

    ...
}
```

One child entity:

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class Identifier  {

    @NotNull(groups = { CheckId.class })
    @NotBlank(groups = { CheckId.class })
    @Id
    @Column(length = 32)
    private String id = IdGenerator.createId();

    @Version
    private Integer version;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable=false, length=3)
    @Index(name = "idx_id_prod_type")
    private String type;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable=false, length=65)
    @Index(name = "idx_id_prod_value")
    private String value;

    ...
}
```

There are lots of such @OneToMany relations with different (but structurally similar) entities in Product. Millions of records are written correctly, but in most of them I occasionally encounter some hundreds with product_id null. How is this possible?

Unfortunately I cannot easily determine when this happens (due to the missing product_id). Also product_id is not part of the Envers history table of the child entities. So I cannot examine if the product still exists, and what the services have done with it lately.

For information: when a child entity is removed from the parent, this is done via

```
product.getIdentifiers.remove(identifier);

or

product.getIdentifiers.removeAll(identifiers);

or

product.getIdentifiers.clear();
```

This is hopefully a valid way to remove them ;)

Comment: Check if this will help you http://coderclubs.com/questions/5096174/hibernate-one-to-many-relation-foreign-key-always-null

Comment: @SubodhJoshi Thanks, but this is not the problem. Millions of records are inserted correctly; but sometimes these orphans occur. The relation is just one way.

Comment: @UweAllner have you found solution to this issue or do you know what is causing it ? If so, could you provide answer to your question here ?

Comment: @myhau If I knew I would do so. But unfortunately I don't...

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand you use `FetchType.LAZY` - it mean the data will be retrieved only during the session, you can use `Hibernate.initialize` for retrieving `@OneToMany`  fields or can use `FetchType.EAGER` instead `FetchType.LAZY`

Comment: But this does not explain why I have records with product_id null in the database. Records with non-null values are loaded correctly, if lazy or not.